# pandas DatatFrame.corr returns a one by one DF

Tags: pandas

I can't get what is possibly wrong in the way I use df.corr() function.
For a DF with 2 columns it returns only 1*1 resulting DF.

In:
    `merged_df[['Citable per Capita','Citations']].corr()`

Out:
[one by one resulting DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwod6.png)

What can be the problem here? I expected to see as many rows and columns as many columns were there in the original DF

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem - it was the wrong dtype of the first column values.

To change type of all the columns, use:
`df=df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))`

Note that `apply` creates a copy of df. That is why reassignment is necessary here

Comment: Write your question and answer up better and you might get some upvotes.  read these links for guidance http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask